# How can I solve a problem with saving and getting data JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input which is getting converted into an array. I want that the list `ulist` is showing everything you have typed in the input. The function `savemonday()` is working like I want but at `start()` every letter of the array is in an extra `ul` element.

```html
<body onload="start(); return false">
  <header>
    <a href="/index.html">Montag</a>
    <a href="">Dienstag</a>
    <a href="">Mittwoch</a>
    <a href="">Donnerstag</a>
    <a href="">Freitag</a>
  </header>

  <form onsubmit="savemonday(); return false">
    <div>
      <input required id="inMonday" type="text" />

      <button>Hinzufügen</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <br />

  <ul id="ulist"></ul>
</body>
```

```js
let monday = localStorage.getItem('monday') || {};

function savemonday() {
  monday[inMonday.value] = inMonday.value;
  start();

  document.getElementById('inMonday').value = '';

  localStorage.setItem('monday', JSON.stringify(monday));
}

function start() {
  ulist.innerHTML = '';
  for (let key in monday) {
    ulist.innerHTML += `<li>${monday[key]}</li>`;
  }
}
```

Comment: `ulist` and `inMonday` are not declared

Comment: they are declared

Comment: I can't believe my eyes. I honestly didn't know html elements were accessible in javascript simply by referring to their ID - thank you sir

Comment: I think this solves it: `let monday = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('monday')) || {};`